# Webform in Lightbox, close in submit

Tags: webforms, forms, javascript

I have a form (webform) in a lightbox. I created a link:

```
<a class="lightbox-processed" rel="lightframe" href="?q=node/29/lightbox2">show Form</a>
```

and change 'page--node--lightbox2.tpl.php' (tpl from lightbox2 module) for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>">
<head>
</head>
<body id="lightboxnode-<?php print $node->type ?>">

<?php //dsm($node); ?>

<?php if ($title): ?>
<h1 class="title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
    $nodo = $node->nid;
    print render(node_view(node_load($nodo), 'full', NULL));
?>
</body>
 </html>
```

How can I do for when I click submit, send the form and close the lightbox?

Comment: i'll recommend you to use http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jQuery to detect the button click on the submit button and then force the action of closing the lightbox with `parent.Lightbox.end();`.

The reason I would use jQuery to attach to the event is that you don't have to alter the webform in any way, and can do this passively.